# Developer console shows line breaks when there are none

Tags: developer-console, line-break

We have some `EmailMessage` records where the `htmlbody` field has its value from the `textbody` of email records taken from Microsoft Outlook using the Graph API implying there should be no newline/line break characters.

So I query `EmailMessage` records and run the following script in apex:

```
for (EmailMessage em : [select id, htmlbody from emailmessage]) {
    if (
        em.htmlbody == null 
        || em.htmlbody.contains('<br>') 
        || em.htmlbody.contains('<br/>')
        || em.htmlbody.contains('<br />')
        || em.htmlbody.contains('\\n')
        || em.htmlbody.contains('\\r')
    ) continue;
    
    system.debug(em.htmlbody);
}
```

The problem I'm having upon logging to the console is that on the console, I see the emails with line breaks, as if they really have line breaks of some kind. Please see the very redacted screenshot below:
[image: screenshot of issue]

What am I missing here? I expect to see one long string of text whereas I see a string with line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find literal line breaks, you need to use `\r` or `\n`, not `\\r` or `\\n`, which represent two characters (`\r` and `\n`, respectively).

```
    || em.htmlbody.contains('\n')
    || em.htmlbody.contains('\r')
```